# Hexadecimal Number convertor

Tags: c, recursion

i trying to write a Recursion function that get a decimal number and print the value in hexadecimal 
but i dont know what worng in my code 
please help me i still new in Recursion and dont get it complitly...

```
    my code:

void PrintHexadecimalNumber(int n)
{
    if (n%16==0)
        return ;

    PrintHexadecimalNumber(n/16);

    switch ((n % 16))// A-F cases
    {
    case (10):
        printf("A");
        break;
    case (11):
        printf("B");
        break;
    case (12):
        printf("C");
        break;
    case (13):
        printf("D");
        break;
    case (14):
        printf("E");
        break;
    case (15):
        printf("F");
        break;
    }

    if ((n%16)<10)
        printf(n%16);

}
```

Comment: `printf(n%16);` ----> `printf("%d", n%16);`

Comment: cant belive it was that stupid shame on me -_-

Comment: thank man its look like its works

Comment: I hope you realise that using recursion is often an indication of poor design. In this case, you could just use `printf("%x", n);`, unless learning about recursion is the goal, of course. This will likely teach you the pitfalls of recursion.

Comment: @monkey.D.Ganga try it with number completely divisible by 16 like 128. it will come out without printing anything. because of that `if(n%16==0)` condition. instead u can use `if(n==0)
return ;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code isn't going to work because of the test you've written to stop the recursion.

```
if (n%16==0)
```

If you have the number (in hex) 10, the function will stop immediately because n % 16 will be 0. What you actually want to test for is when `n` is 0. Like this

```
if (n==0)
```

Your `switch` statement should also be expanded out to include the values 0 to 9 rather than having a separate `if` statement after it. You can group them together by leaving out the `break`

```
switch(n % 16)
   {
/* existing case statements go here */
case 0:
case 1:
case 2:
...
case 9:
   printf("%d",n % 16); // also fixing this as per comments above.
break;
   }
```

Or you could just use `printf("%x",n % 16)` and do away with the `switch` completely if what you're trying to do is explore how recursion works.